# How can I find every arrangement of a data array of values

Tags: vba, math, statistics

Array/matrix/permutations/combinations problem:

x = [a,b,c,d,e];

Each element in 'x' can take on one of three values, (-1, 0 or 1), for simplicity as each element may have different values.

I need to find every possible "arrangement"

```
x = [0,0,0,0,0]
x = [0,0,0,0,1]
x = [0,0,0,1,0]
x = [0,0,0,1,0]
x = [0,0,1,0,0]
x = [0,1,0,0,0]
x = [1,0,0,0,0]
...
x = [1,1,1,1,1]
...
x = [1,-1,0,-1,1]
...
x = [-1,-1,-1,-1,-1]
etc.
```

I think, there should be 3^5 = 243 possibilities?  It's OK if some arrangements are repeated.

I'm assuming I need to store the values in a 2D matrix:

```
x =
[
    a[-1, 0, 1],
    b[-1, 0, 1],
    c[-1, 0, 1],
    d[-1, 0, 1],
    e[-1, 0, 1]
];
```

which lends itself to looking at each "row" and "column":

```
for each row in x
    for each column in x
        //do something with x(row, column)
    next column
next row
```

I'm currently working in VBA, but (almost) any coded solution or pseudo-code will help.

Comment: Assuming that the size of the array is fixed at 5 then simply five nested for loops will get you the required combinations. If the size is not fixed then you are looking at a recursive solution (which could be used for a fixed size as well of course).

Comment: Thanks John.  I had an inkling recursion might be required, but it's been a long, long time since I was at school!

You're right about the size of the arrays; now there are five elements in the array and each element will have one of three values, however, the final project will have probably 17 elements each with four (five?) possible values (Yes, it's going to be a huge solution set).  

Recursion is not my strong point (and gives me a headache!)  How would I recurse this data, and what would I set as the endpoint?

Comment: I've updated the answer below with a recursive solution, but recursion is only necessary to initialise the array, not to traverse it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A C++ solution assuming a fixed size of five

```
#include <array>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::array<int, 5>> x;
for (int a = -1; a <= 1; ++a)
    for (int b = -1; b <= 1; ++b)
        for (int c = -1; c <= 1; ++c)
            for (int d = -1; d <= 1; ++d)
                for (int e = -1; e <= 1; ++e)
                    x.emplace_back(std::array<int, 5>{ a, b, c, d, e });
```

And a recursive solution for varying sizes (here 10)

```
#include <vector>

void init(std::vector<std::vector<int>>& x, std::vector<int>& row, size_t max_depth)
{
    if (row.size() == max_depth)
    {
        x.push_back(row);
    }
    else
    {
        for (int a = -1; a <= 1; ++a)
        {
            row.push_back(a);
            init(x, row, max_depth);
            row.pop_back();
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> x;
    std::vector<int> row;
    init(x, row, 10);
}
```

Comment: Wow!  I would never have come up with that recursive solution.  Thanks.  I'll have a play and see if I can cause my CPU to meltdown!